# Can I login gmail before use selenium to click gmail menu?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to use selenium click gmail menu but when I run selenium it alway have to login gmail. Can I login gmail for bypass login before use selenium to click gmail menu?

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/?ogbl#inbox')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium to login for you with your username and password:

```
email = browser.find_element_by_id('Email')
email.send_keys('username')
next_button = browser.find_element_by_id('next')
next_button.click()
time.sleep(1)
password = browser.find_element_by_id('Passwd')
password.send_keys('password')
login = browser.find_element_by_id('signIn')
login.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

One way or another you will have to login to gmail. I am not a selenium expert buy why can't you simply do the following:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/?ogbl#inbox')
input('Manually login and hit return when done:')
# continue from the post-login screen (i.e. the inbox)
```

But it would probably be simpler to just program the login as suggested by @olenscki (I have not verified whether his solution works or not).